# Boot linux from USB, but my medium is corrupt/damaged, what to do?

Tags: system-installation

I'm having the following problem. I was installing Linux from USB and during the installation I had a power outage. Now I've apparently broken GRUB and I can't boot from the USB.

What to do?

I don't have a CDROM/DVD of the installation, only USB. I cannot recover GRUB because I have an apparently empty `(hd0,msdos)` partition(s).

Answer (score 1):

Without this install medium you're pretty much out of luck. You'll need to get another source for doing your installation if the USB medium has become damaged/corrupt.

You should be able to download new distro and rewrite it to the USB device you already have. You can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to write an ISO file to a USB thumb drive. UNetbootin runs on all OSes.

*excerpt from UNetbootin website*

> UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu, Fedora, and other Linux distributions without burning a CD. It runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X. You can either let UNetbootin download one of the many distributions supported out-of-the-box for you, or supply your own Linux .iso file if you've already downloaded one or your preferred distribution isn't on the list.

[image: ss of unetbootin]